# Clicking an element with ui-sref within another element with ui-sref

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, dom-events

I have a `div` with an `ui-sref` attribute such that I am essentially treating it as a big button; however, within that `div` I have an actual `button` that also has an `ui-sref` attribute, but it is pointed to a different state.

When I click on the button, the state referenced by the `button` flashes on the screen before being replaced by the state referenced by the `div`.

How do I get only the `button` to set the state upon clicking it?

```
<div ui-sref="loadDocument({doc: documentName})">
  {{documentName}}
  <button class="btn" ui-sref="viewMetadata({doc: documentName})">
    View Metadata
  </button>
</div>
```

Comment: Why would you require 2 **different states maintenance**  as an essentially you are treating it as a single big button ? You can achieve both of the states/template work (business logic ) in single state using only one single button with  nested states/views or using abstract property of the state likewise.

Answer (score 0):

Not feasible, always parent element click will called.

try this

```
<div">
  <span ui-sref="loadDocument({doc: documentName})"> {{documentName}}</span>
  <button class="btn" ui-sref="viewMetadata({doc: documentName})">
    View Metadata
  </button>
</div>
```